# parent bones in blender

Tags: bones, parent

[image: passive menu]

Hi, in edit mode I can't parent the bone the other bone because parenting menu gets passive , the other bones what I try I can parent them.you can see in image

Comment: These bones are probably part of 2 separate armatures. If for some reason you really want to parent a bone to a bone of another armature you can use a *Child Of* bone constraint.

Comment: @moonboots This is a complete answer to the question. Please post it as such.

Comment: @TheLabCat ok I just wanted to be sure  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These bones are probably part of 2 different armatures. If for some reason you really want to parent a bone of an armature to a bone of another armature you can use a *Child Of* bone constraint:

[image]

Comment: Thank you master :)