# Why can't I connect my head/face armature to my body armature using parent, bone constraints, or anything!

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a perfectly working body rig, everything is parented and works fine. I have a face rig that does everything that I want it to do. The eyes and teeth follow the head and the bones for the lips and jaw all work as well as I could hope for my first lip rig! The only thing I regret is not adding some eyebrow bones, but that wasn't in the tutorial I watched anyway.

Problem is, If I move the 'neck' portion of the body, all of the bones paired with the face just stay in place. The head and body don't interact at all so I would have to switch between object and pose mode to use the two armatures as is; which makes sense, because the two aren't parented or joined. But no matter which way I try to combine everything (even just one at a time, like only the eye + body, then teeth etc.) something stops working.

Mainly, The head bone suddenly locks up if parented to the body and none of the face bones work. If the body is parented to the face, then for some reason the face mesh follows the movements about 2-5 seconds behind so the teeth and eyes are always flying outside the mesh flesh. If 'joined', then the entire thing loses all connection to mesh and the bones don't move anything at all.

I've tried looking up 'how to connect face rig/armature/bones to body rig/armature/bones' but that's an elusive topic apparently. I'm really at a loss and don't want to have to re-rig everything just because Blender decided that I can't combine my two good rigs for no reason.

I've even tried applying the rig modifiers, but that literally made my computer explode, and then when I re-tried it after a restart it didn't help at all.

Here's the problem child today: [image]

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275338/parent-bones-in-blender

Comment: No, but thanks. I tried this for the last hour. No combination of parenting or xyz did anything close to right.

Comment: Since your head armature is just four bones and a couple of constraints, I'd be inclined to delete it and rebuild the head armature from the body bone. As you've found out, Blender doesn't like using two connected armatures.

Comment: That is exactly what I've done, lol. I deleted the head and made a new one as apt of the already existing body. Repainted everything and it seems to be working fine. Still, I wish connecting the two was an option. It would have saved me a lot of stress and time!